# How to control job scheduling in a better way in gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, rundeck

I have in my gitlab projects jobs defined and executed via gitlab-ci. However, it doesn't do well with interdependent jobs as there's no management of this case except manual. 
The case I have is a service, which is a part of the overall app, takes long time to start. Starting this service is done within a job, while another job have another service, which is also a part of the overall app, querying the former service. Due to interdependence, I have just delayed the execution of this later job so that most probably the former job has its service up and running.
I wanted to use Rundeck as a job scheduler but not sure if this can be done with gitlab? Maybe I am wrong about gitlab, so does gitlab allow better job scheduling?

Here's an example of what I am doing:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
deploy:
  environment:
    name:$CI_ENVIRONMENT
    url: http://$CI_ENVIRONMENT.local.net:4999/
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - sudo dpkg -i myapp.deb
    - sleep 30m //here I wait for the service to be ready for later jobs to run successfully
    - RESULT=`curl http://localhost:9999/api/test | grep Success'
```

Comment: better add code sample or your flow chart with stage name, then others can give sample and suggestion. or link to existing demo gitlab proj

Comment: @LarryCai Ok I did that.

Comment: remove some non-related information to make questions clearly

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it is a typical trigger feature inside gitlab-ci

see [gitlab-ci triggers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)

mostly at the end of the long start-up service job A to use `curl` to trigger another one

```
deploy_service_a:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - "curl --request POST --form token=TOKEN --form ref=master https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline"
  only:
  - tags
```